# How to alias current working directory

Tags: linux, matlab, directory, tmp

I have some very disk intensive cluster jobs that I'd like to process in the /tmp space on each compute node. The jobs are submitted to a grid engine and then distributed to any number of nodes, each node has a large local /tmp directory. The nodes are all CentOS, and share a common NFS mount.

For each job, I'd like to be able to copy all the data from it's NFS location to the /tmp directory, do the processing, and copy it back out to its original NFS location. However, the processing stream is generic, meaning any command line programs could be launched as part of a job. Some of the programs we run, like MATLAB, like to expand soft links to the actual path and also store full paths in the processed data.

I've only thought of one way to do this, but I wanted to see if there is a better way.

1) Create a link from the NFS directory to "/tmp/blah/thelocaljobstempdir", so that all references to that directory are directed to the /tmp. Then after processing is done, move the /tmp directory to its final location and remove the link. This may work for some jobs, but not those that expand their paths and/or store full paths in the data.

Basically, how can I make a program think it is working in one path, when its actually working in a different path, without using hard links since the directories are on different filesystems?

Answer (score 0):

You could try a `bind mount`.

```
mount --bind nfsdir /tmp/nfsdir
```

Whit a *bind mount* you make a file hierarchy accesible in another filesystem place. For more info `man mount` is a good starting point.